Executable binary file generated with MPLAB is abnormally huge, why?
I am working with MPLAB-X-IDE ver 5.45 and compiler xc-16 ver 1.61.
It builds an executable file in .hex format. As I need a binary .bin file, i generate it by telling the compiler to run this macro:
${MP_CC_DIR}\xc16-objcopy -I ihex -O binary "${DISTDIR}/${PROJECTNAME}.${IMAGE_TYPE}.hex" "${DISTDIR}/${PROJECTNAME}.${IMAGE_TYPE}.bin"

The .bin file is created but the problem is that it sizes 684 kbytes and the orginal .hex file has only 73 kbytes.
I need smaller file and I cannot understand why the binary format is so big as it should be even smaller than the hexadecimal file which is in text format.
I noticed that the binary file contains thousands of consecutive zeros between which seems to be the end of the program and a final "row" (check sum, file termination trailer, other?) at the end of the file.
So my questions:

Why the binary file is much bigger than the .hex file?
Is there any way to reduce the size of the binary file?


Have you tried doing it on a toy example like "hello world" ? These sort of huge expansions in size tend to occur when linker symbol tables for debugging get added to the binary file and/or something decides to pad every routine to a 4k boundary. A fold increase from a hex file to a .bin does seem excessive.

@MartinBrown Even if I try a simple toy example and I discover that the bin is smaller than the hex it does not solve my problem. I need a procedure to obtain a bin of reasonable smaller size, if it exists...

It will give you some hints about what is going on though. Something is padding out the .bin file to a silly size - you need to figure out what.

Any idea about where start from? Thanks
